# To slay the helpless angle

Tags: meaning, etymology

From Guy Wetmore Carryl's "[The Precipitate Cock and the Unappreciated Pearl](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Precipitate_Cock_and_the_Unappreciated_Pearl)":

> He turned again to where his clan
>
> In one astounding tangle
>
> With eager haste together ran
>
> To slay the helpless **angle**

The author uses "angle" to refer to a worm, a key hero of the narrative.
Does the meaning of *angle* here stems from the geometrical figure, or from the archaic sense of *hook* [listed in the Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/angle--2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q: Does the meaning of *angle* here stems from the geometrical figure, or from the archaic sense of *hook* listed in the Oxford Dictionary?**

It's short for *angle worm*, which gets its name from the fishing hook.

The OED defines *angleworm* as:

> An earthworm of a kind used for bait by anglers.

They say it's chiefly US and the author Guy Wetmore Carryl was also American. His poem was published in 1898 and the OED has quotations from 1788 onwards, and the 18th and 19th centuries are of the form *angle-worm* or *angle worm*.

The OED says the *angle* of *angle worm* originally was a fish hook and goes way, way back to early Old English, with cognates in Germanic languages and etymologically is:

> ultimately < the same Indo-European base as ancient Greek *ἀγκύλος* crooked, curved  (see further angle n.2 [geometrical etc.]).

---

How about the geometrical angle? Well, it's related to the fishing hook, but the common ancestors are a long way back. The OED says the first use of this word was a corner, recess or nook of a room or enclosed space; used this way before 1325. It also meant a point of land; a cape, or promontory; used before 1387. Other geometrical meanings are from before 1398.

Etymologically these came to English through Anglo-Norman, Old French, Middle French,

> ultimately showing a variant of the same Indo-European base as ancient Greek *ἀγκών* bend of the arm, nook, bend, angle, *ἀγκύλος* crooked, curved, and angle n.1 [the fishing hook]

Finally, the names of England and English come from the Germanic tribe Angles, which may derive from a place called Angeln (on the German coast near the Danish border) which itself may come from the fishing hook.

Comment: Great! You really explained it hook, line and sinker, Hugo. (0:

Answer (score 5):

From the Wikipedia article on [Earthworm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm):

> Folk names for the earthworm include "dew-worm", "rainworm", "night
>   crawler", and "angleworm" (due to its use as fishing bait).

So it would be because of the archaic sense of angle, although the word "angle" as a word for fishing isn't so archaic as all that.  "Angler" is a common word for a fisherman who fishes uses a hook and line; "angling" is a noun referencing the activity.

Comment: This is what I assumed too, but I've never actually seen *angle worm* shortened to *angle* before.

Comment: You've never seen it rhyme with "tangle" either ;)